# Почему PHP функция array_keys работает не так как ожидалось

Tags: php

Пример кода:

```
$input = array(    
    52058 => '7008E-805',
    52059 => '7008E-806',
    52060 => '7010-805',
    52061 => '7012J-805',
    52062 => '7012J-805'
);
$search_value = '7008E-805';
$strict = false;
$result = array_keys($input, $search_value, $strict);
print_r($result);
```

На выходе получаем:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 52058
    [1] => 52059
)
```

Почему? Ведь ожидается, что будет найден только один ключ.

Если мы поставим:

```
$strict = true;
```

то все работает правильно. Но кажется, что так должно быть и без $strict = true.

Кстати, пример кода - это разбор кусочка реальных данных. Во всех других случаях array_keys работает как надо и только при поиске '7008E-805' дает такой странный результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.numeric-strings.php

Потому что `7008E-805` это валидная числовая строка 7008×10<sup>-805</sup>, но поскольку это выходит за возможности представления чисел с плавающей точкой, то это значение приводится к нулю. Вторая строка аналогично приводится к нулю и мы получаем два нулевых значения которые array_keys и нашёл.

Именно поэтому и нужно использовать строгое сравнение, что бы PHP не пытался «играть с типами».

Comment: Но вообще кейс забавный, с первого взгляда, особенно в контексте остальных значений, и не опознаешь что это может быть число

Comment: Спасибо! Да, действительно - именно контекст похоже сбил меня с толку.